# Isar database backup locally and restore

Tags: database, flutter, nosql, flutter-isar

I want to know if there is a way by which I can export all the database of the Isar into a backup and then restore it so if a user wants to uninstall the app the user can backup the data locally into a location like sdcard or phone storage and after reinstalling they can restore from backup all the database and can use it again. So what can be the ways by which it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use isar.copyToFile()
look at the following post on Isar's github:
https://github.com/isar/isar/issues/579